# need to display some edittext fields if user is checked on checkbox otherwise not to display it

Tags: java, android, checkbox, ischecked

i have to develop one registration form android app.here i have to enter the edittext field is automatically save in mysql database via soap webservices calling.

Here i have to follow my additional requirement is

1. The shipping and biling address is same means have to check the checkbox also have to enter billing address edittext field only at the same time the shipping address edittext field is have to display invisible also billing address  have to save in shipping address database fields also.
2. The billing and shipping address is different means have to uncheck the checkbox and also have to display the shipping address edittext filed is visible.

   (i.e)I need to display some edittext fields if user is checked on checkbox otherwise not to display it.

How can i develop these.please help me.

I have used below code:

```
public class NewCustomer extends Activity{
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://xcart.com";
private final String URL = "http://10.0.0.75:8085/XcartLogin/services/RetailerWs?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xcart.com/insertData";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "insertData";
CheckBox chkRememberMe;

Button btninsert;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_customer);

    btninsert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
    btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             
             EditText Baddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_address);
             EditText Bcity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_city);
             EditText Bstate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_state);
             EditText Bcountry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_country);
             EditText Bzipcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_zipcode);
             EditText Saddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_address1);
             EditText Scity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_city1);
             EditText Sstate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_state1);
             EditText Szipcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_zipcode1);
             EditText Scountry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_country1);
        if(!(Baddress.getText().toString().length() == 0)){
                         if(!(Bcity.getText().toString().length() == 0)){
                             if(!(Bstate.getText().toString().length() == 0)){
                                 if(!(Bcountry.getText().toString().length() == 0)){
                                    if((checkZipcode1(zipcode1))){
                                         if(!(Saddress.getText().toString().length() == 0)){
                                             if(!(Scity.getText().toString().length() == 0)){
                                                 if(!(Sstate.getText().toString().length() == 0)){
                                                     if(!(Scountry.getText().toString().length() == 0)){
                                                         if((checkZipcode(zipcode))){
                     insertValues();
                       }   
                                                         else{
                                                              showAlertbox("Enter the 5 or 6 digit valid zipcode)!!"); 

                                                      }
                                                    }
                                                     else{
                                                             showAlertbox("Country is Required!!"); 

                                                  }
                                                }
                                                 else{
                                                      showAlertbox("State is Required!!"); 

                                              }
                                            }
                                             else{
                                                  showAlertbox("City is Required!!"); 

                                          }
                                        }else{
                                               showAlertbox("Address is Required!!"); 

                                       }
                                     }
                                     else{
                                          showAlertbox("Enter the 5 or 6 digit valid zipcode)!!"); 

                                  }
                                }
                                 else{
                                      showAlertbox("Country is Required!!"); 

                              }
                            }
                             else{
                                  showAlertbox("State is Required!!"); 

                          }
                        }
                         else{
                              showAlertbox("City is Required!!"); 

                      }
                    }else{
                           showAlertbox("Address is Required!!"); 

                   }
            }

         });
    
     }

         public void showAlertbox(String erroMessage) {
                 AlertDialog alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getParent())
    .create();
           // Setting Dialog Message
            alertdialog.setTitle("Error Message");
           alertdialog.setMessage(erroMessage);
          alertdialog.setButton("OK",
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //finish();
            return;
        }
    });

        alertdialog.show();

}

                
             

public void insertValues(){
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
  EditText Baddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_address);
 String baddr = Baddress.getText().toString();
 EditText Bcity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_city);
 String bcity = Bcity.getText().toString();
 EditText Bstate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_state);
 String bstate = Bstate.getText().toString();
 EditText Bcountry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_country);
 String bcountry = Bcountry.getText().toString();
 EditText Bzipcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_zipcode);
 String bzipcode = Bzipcode.getText().toString();
 EditText Saddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_address1);
 String saddr = Saddress.getText().toString();
 EditText Scity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_city1);
 String scity = Scity.getText().toString();
 EditText Sstate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_state1);
 String sstate = Sstate.getText().toString();
 EditText Scountry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_country1);
 String scountry = Scountry.getText().toString();
 EditText Szipcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_zipcode1);
 String szipcode = Szipcode.getText().toString();
  PropertyInfo baddress =new PropertyInfo();
    baddress.setName("Baddress");//Define the variable name in the web service method
    baddress.setValue(baddr);//Define value for fname variable
    baddress.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
    request.addProperty(baddress);//Pass properties to the variable
   
  //Pass value for userPassword variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo bci =new PropertyInfo();
    bci.setName("Bcity");
    bci.setValue(bcity);
    bci.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(bci);
    PropertyInfo bsta =new PropertyInfo();
    bsta.setName("Bstate");//Define the variable name in the web service method
    bsta.setValue(bstate);//Define value for fname variable
    bsta.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
    request.addProperty(bsta);//Pass properties to the variable
   
  //Pass value for userPassword variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo bcoun =new PropertyInfo();
    bcoun.setName("Bcountry");
    bcoun.setValue(bcountry);
    bcoun.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(bcoun); 
    PropertyInfo bzip =new PropertyInfo();
    bzip.setName("Bzipcode");
    bzip.setValue(bzipcode);
    bzip.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(bzip); 
    PropertyInfo saddress =new PropertyInfo();
    saddress.setName("Saddress");//Define the variable name in the web service method
    saddress.setValue(saddr);//Define value for fname variable
    saddress.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
    request.addProperty(saddress);//Pass properties to the variable
   
  //Pass value for userPassword variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo sci =new PropertyInfo();
    sci.setName("Scity");
    sci.setValue(scity);
    sci.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(sci);
    PropertyInfo ssta =new PropertyInfo();
    ssta.setName("Sstate");//Define the variable name in the web service method
    ssta.setValue(sstate);//Define value for fname variable
    ssta.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
    request.addProperty(ssta);//Pass properties to the variable
   
  //Pass value for userPassword variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo scoun =new PropertyInfo();
    scoun.setName("Scountry");
    scoun.setValue(scountry);
    scoun.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(scoun); 
    PropertyInfo szip =new PropertyInfo();
    szip.setName("Szipcode");
    szip.setValue(szipcode);
    szip.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(szip);
       SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
  
    try{
     androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
         
        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        result.setText(response.toString());
        chkRememberMe = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.addresscheckbox);
           //testing if it is checked or unchecked
            if (chkRememberMe.isChecked())
            {
                //if it is check
                Saddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }else{
                Saddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
           
        
 }
 catch(Exception e){
   
 }
    
}
```

}

how can i develop above my requirements.please give me some solutions.

**EDIT:**

I have changed my code below look like:

```
chkIos = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.addresscheckbox);
     
    chkIos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 
      public void onClick(View v) {
                //is chkIos checked?
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            Saddress.setEnabled(false);
        }
 
      }
    });
```

Now i have to run the application and check the checkbox means my console window shows following error.

```
01-24 13:39:12.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1327): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 13:39:12.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1327): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-24 13:39:12.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at com.ssmobileproductions.catalogue.NewCustomer$1.onClick(NewCustomer.java:69)
01-24 13:39:12.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-24 13:39:12.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
01-24 13:39:12.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
01-24 13:39:12.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 01-24 13:39:12.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 01-24 13:39:12.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  01-24 13:39:12.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
  01-24 13:39:12.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   01-24 13:39:12.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  01-24 13:39:12.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
   01-24 13:39:12.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
   01-24 13:39:12.034: E/AndroidRuntime(1327):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I got the above error while i have clicked the check box.how can i resolve these error.please help me.

**EDIT:**

```
chkIos = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.addresscheckbox);
        
    chkIos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
        {
             S_address = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address1);  
             S_address.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
          
        Saddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tf_address1);  
        Saddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
      }
        else
        {
             S_address = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address1);  
             S_address.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
          
       Saddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tf_address1);  
        Saddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
     }
    });
```

Now i have to run the application and check the checkbox means the shipping address is invible...i have to uncheck the checkbox means the shipping address is visible.

Now my doubt is if i have to check the checkbox means how can i save the saddress value in database.here i have to save the baddress value is save in saddress  field also...

Answer (score 0):

I would have all of the edit fields on screen at all times, but have them ones you don't want them to enter data into disabled (by calling editText.setEnable(false)) if the checkbox is checked.  To do that, register an onClickListener for the checkbox and in your listener get the currnt state of the checkbox and enable/disable accordingly.

Comment: Hi The shipping and billing address is same means have to check the checkbox also have to enter billing address edittext field only at the same time the shipping address edittext field is have to display invisible also its automatically have to save in both billing and shipping address database fields.
How can i do???? Here the Saddress.setEnable(false); means how can i save the Baddress value to Saddress value in database.